# ng-tags project is not observing fieldset disabled. Any Suggestions or workarounds?

Tags: angularjs-directive, ng-tags-input

I am using ng-tags in my angular app and certain views I have fieldset=isdisabled();  All my inputs are disabled as expected; however, ng-tags does not observe this.

Has anyone else ran across this or have a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

That feature is currently not available. But it's already [in the project backlog](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues/102).